# how to pass the name of dataframe list inside a list using a loop in r

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have a list of dataframes where I try to apply a function. My function should iterate 3 times. After each iteration the results should be saved on the `results` list.

My data frames have numeric content and different names of columns except for the last 6 columns (which have the same name).

My code is as follows:

```
# suposse i have three df with the following names
myfirstdf 
myseconddf
mythirddf 

mydflist # a list containing 3 data frames
for (i in 1:3){
results[[i]] <- lapply(mydflist, function(x) {         
longdata <- ncol(x)-i
sum ( x[,1:longdata])
} )

names(results[[i]]) <- sprintf("results[[i]]", 1:length(results))
}
```

What I want to do is to access to the results of each dataframe by adding the ith number of iteration, something like: 
`results$mydflist$myfirstdfi`where `i`will be the number of iteration so `results$mydflist$myfirstdf1`. But with my code I've got `results$results1$results1`

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood something, it might be more convenient to reverse the order of your `for` loop and `lapply`; i.e. (1) build a function that takes a "data.frame", iterates 3 times, adds a column each time and, returns the result, (2) `lapply` your function over "mydflist". Perhaps, an example `mydflist` and wanted output will help better.

Comment: I've just edited my question, hope is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces a list of length 3, the number of iterations, and each of the three list items is again a list of length 3, the number of dataframes in `mydflist`.
But from the formulation

> What I want to do is to access to the results of each dataframe by
>   adding the ith number of iteration, something like:
>   results$mydflist$myfirstdfi where i will be the number of iteration so
>   results$mydflist$myfirstdf1.

in your question I guess what you really want is a *flat* list of length 9, containing one item for each each iteration step and each dataframe in `mydflist`, named

"myfirstdf1"  "myseconddf1" "mythirddf1"

"myfirstdf2"  "myseconddf2" "mythirddf2"

"myfirstdf3"  "myseconddf3" "mythirddf3".

The following function can handle both cases:

```
iteration <- function( dfList, fnct, numberOfIterations, flat=TRUE )
{
  L <- list()

  for (i in 1:numberOfIterations){
    L[[i]] <- lapply( dfList, fnct, i )
    names(L[[i]]) <- paste0( names(dfList), i )
  }
  return( if (flat) unlist(L,recursive=FALSE) else L )
}
```

Example:

```
mydflist <- list(
  myfirstdf  = data.frame(matrix(1:20,4,5)),
  myseconddf = data.frame(matrix(1:12,2,6)),
  mythirddf  = data.frame(matrix(1:15,3,5))
)

f <- function(df,i)
{
  longdata <- ncol(df)-i
  sum(df[,1:longdata])
}

results      <- iteration(mydflist,f,4,FALSE)
results_flat <- iteration(mydflist,f,4)
```

(I've changed the number of iterations from 3 to 4, to avoid confusion with the number of dataframes.)
Here is the resulting list `results`, which is *not* flat:

```
> results
[[1]]
[[1]]$myfirstdf1
[1] 136

[[1]]$myseconddf1
[1] 55

[[1]]$mythirddf1
[1] 78


[[2]]
[[2]]$myfirstdf2
[1] 78

[[2]]$myseconddf2
[1] 36

[[2]]$mythirddf2
[1] 45


[[3]]
[[3]]$myfirstdf3
[1] 36

[[3]]$myseconddf3
[1] 21

[[3]]$mythirddf3
[1] 21

[[4]]
[[4]]$myfirstdf4
[1] 10

[[4]]$myseconddf4
[1] 10

[[4]]$mythirddf4
[1] 6
```

Notice that the number of the iteration step appears twice. For example the result for third dataframe in the first iteration step is

```
> results[[1]]$mythirddf1
[1] 78
```

In the names of the *flat* list `results_flat` the number of the iteration step appears only once:

```
> results_flat
$myfirstdf1
[1] 136

$myseconddf1
[1] 55

$mythirddf1
[1] 78

$myfirstdf2
[1] 78

$myseconddf2
[1] 36

$mythirddf2
[1] 45

$myfirstdf3
[1] 36

$myseconddf3
[1] 21

$mythirddf3
[1] 21

$myfirstdf4
[1] 10

$myseconddf4
[1] 10

$mythirddf4
[1] 6
```

E.g. the result for third dataframe in the first iteration step is

```
> results_flat$mythirddf1
[1] 78
```

If you want to access this result via `results$mydflist$mythirddf1`, then build a one component list `results` as follows:

```
> results <- list(mydflist=iteration(mydflist,f,4))
```

The one and only component of this list `results` is the list `results_flat` above,
and its name is `mydflist`:

```
> results
$mydflist
$mydflist$myfirstdf1
[1] 136

$mydflist$myseconddf1
[1] 55

$mydflist$mythirddf1
[1] 78

$mydflist$myfirstdf2
[1] 78

$mydflist$myseconddf2
[1] 36

$mydflist$mythirddf2
[1] 45

$mydflist$myfirstdf3
[1] 36

$mydflist$myseconddf3
[1] 21

$mydflist$mythirddf3
[1] 21

$mydflist$myfirstdf4
[1] 10

$mydflist$myseconddf4
[1] 10

$mydflist$mythirddf4
[1] 6
```

Comment: I've edited and enhanced my answer. Hopefully now it contains the desired `results`.

Comment: The edited answer works perfectly! Thanks!! may i question: does the difference between `results`and `results_flat`is only when I want to access to each list?